# App reject on play store due to privacy policy violation

Tags: android

I use MediaStore api for delete images and also used for images and video fetch from storage but still google reject app main app concept is gallery where user show all folder where user can delete and capture images in particular folder. i read that capture images only public dir like camera/pictures and download.

MediaStore used for fatch images and Videos
MediaStore used for delete images bunch

Form particular folder click  show images and video i used file to show videos and images from specific path is the issue ?

```
   <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_MEDIA_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"
        tools:ignore="ScopedStorage" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO" />

    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" />
    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera.autofocus" />
```

[image: issue:Need to use Media Store API]

[image: Not Core Future]

[image: Access to device storage not required]

Comment: try to remove read_external_storage and write_external_storage permissions, if you are not using those. If you still need general file access - try migrating to storage access framework.

Comment: Are you using medistore api correctly? Find any solution where you don't need MANAGE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE permission. Then it's good to go,

Comment: @mehul chauhan, any luck ?

Comment: @MayurRaval used yes i used scope storage than upload